# Access array properties while in a D3 enter() procedure

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am using the following CodePen that displays a tree as a jumping off point for a project: https://codepen.io/augbog/pen/LEXZKK

Inside this pen, it does some wizardry with D3.js to instantiate new nodes when you expand a tree:

```
  // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });
   // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
   var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
       .attr("class", "node")
       .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
   })
       .on("click", click);
```

From my understanding of the [docs](https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh-cn/master/Selections/), enter() is being called for each entry in array "nodes" greater than the selection that happens up above.

Where I'm losing the thread is the very next line.

```
    nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    ...
```

Is this code being called once per new node that needs to be created by enter()? It doesn't look like a loop to me, but somehow these svg attributes are applied to all nodes! Maybe this update function is happening once per new node? That doesn't quite sound like the way enter() is described in the docs.

Anyway, the real issue - stemming from this confusion about what context I'm in when we get to the next few lines - is how to access the attributes of the original tree while creating these new nodes via enter().

```
// vvv ADDED LINE: Doesn't work!
if ( nodeEnter.name != "abc" )
// ^^^ ADDED LINE
nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
});
```

You can see here that by some magic, wrapping things in a function allows the original pen to access the "name" attribute of the current element in the original array. But I tried a couple permutations of the added line (including a callback that checks the condition) and nothing was working out. And since I'm not sure how the magical property accessing callback works and even what context I'm supposed to be in when evaluating this code, I'm not sure what the right way to check the current attributes should be.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For the main part of your question, if you want to access the bound data you need to use something like `selection.each(function(d)...` or `selection.filter(function(d)...` But I'm not sure if I follow what you are looking for. `nodeEnter.name` isn't valid as this isn't a method of a D3 selection, but `selection.filter(function(d) { return d.name != 'abc' })` will return a subselection of elements matching that criteria (Of course, if the element already existed, it won't be in the enter selection).

Comment: As for the loop, the loop is not explicit, the .attr() method of a D3 selection applies a value to an element property for each element the selection holds (using a loop within the method), either using a static value or a passed function (for which the first parameter will be the datum for a given element), returning the same selection.

Comment: Oh, then "nodeEnter" is a group of added nodes, and it's applying these attributes to them all at once - that's making more sense. I was thinking about the way it's doing the loop all backwards. I think I should be able to get it working with some filtering (which, when you reverse the problem, is basically the same as a conditional check for a single element). I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Andrew Reid, "nodeEnter" is a collection of nodes in the sample pen, and not a single node. The equivalent code to filter the collection to only the ones I wanted to apply the attribute to in the example is:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
    .filter(function (d) { return d.name != "abc" })
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
});
```

To be clear, these lines are adding a text SVG element and setting the according attributes to *all* elements in the selection *at once* (There's probably a loop in the API behind the scenes to accomplish this, but it means you don't need a loop in your side of the code). Instead, making new selections or applying additional filters like this after you make a selection is the correct way to selectively set properties.